# Promise-like method

Tags: swift

To explain my question more simply, I will take an example of just outputting to the console.

I have a simple func that takes string and print this to console:

```
func printer(text: String) {
    print(text)
}
```

Sometimes, I need to print text with some additional string

```
func printer(text: String, _ additionalString: String) {
    print(text + additionalString)
}
```

How can I achieve this syntax from caller side:

```
printer(text: "Event").withParam("Tap")
```

> Console Output: EventTap

Comment: I suppose you still want `printer(text: "Event")` to just print "Event", right? What about `printer(text: "Event", "Tap")`? Do you still want that to be valid?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes. If I call printer without .withParam, I want to calls one method, if use with .withParam, I want to calls other method

Comment: your suggested approach means `printer` will do a job if it's result is used and another job if it's return is discarded which can't be done or predicted , hence can't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact syntax cannot be achieved because the methods don't know when you are finished the chain of calls. For example, when `printer` returns, it doesn't and can't know whether you are going to call `withParam` or not, so it can't decide whether to call the method with the argument(s) it has got, or to wait for more arguments.

Therefore, you would need to terminate the chain of calls with another method:

```
printer(text: "Event").withParam("Tap").print()
```

Now that looks a lot like the builder pattern. `printer` could be a class called `Printer`, implemented like this:

```
class Printer {
    private var text: String
    private var param: String?

    init(text: String, _ param: String? = nil) {
        self.text = text
        self.param = param
    }

    func withParam(_ param: String) -> Printer {
        self.param = param
        return self
    }

    func print() {
        if let arg = self.param {
            // I understand that you are referring two two general methods here, not limited to print
            Swift.print(text + arg) // or call the method with two parameters
        } else {
            Swift.print(text) // or call the method with one parameter
        }
    }
}
```

And you could do:

```
Printer(text: "Event").withParam("Tap").print()
// or just
Printer(text: "Event").print()
// or
Printer(text: "Event", "Tap").print()
```

Comment: transforming  a default parameter to a function call then using `if let` isn't the right approach that leads to a trailing function which makes no sense

Comment: @Sh_Khan Can you elaborate? What makes no sense? The trailing function or the act of "transforming a default parameter to a function call then using `if let`"?

Answer (score 0):

To provide a simple alternative - you could just use the default behavior of the print function as a variadic function:

```
print("Event", "Tap")
```

Or define your own variadic method with the one above, if you need to:

```
func printer(_ strings: String...) {
    // 'strings' is an array - pass in as many as you like.
    print(strings.joined())
}
```

Then call

```
// Prints "EventTapEtc"
printer("Event", "Tap", "Etc")
```

---

**EDIT:**
Okay, looks like you want that exact format as above. In which case, this is the best I could come up with. First define a class that will function as your promise:

```
class Printer {

    var string: String

    init(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }

    func addParam(_ string: String) -> Printer {
        self.string += string
        return self
    }

    func print() {
        Swift.print(string)
    }

}
```

Then define your printer function:

```
func printer(_ string: String) -> (Printer) {
    return printer(string)
}
```

And you could call with:

```
printer("hello").addParam("goodbye").print()
```

**SECOND EDIT:**
Looks like the answer above beat me to it! I'd go with that.

Comment: For simple output to console your solution is great, but I exactly want to achieve: printer("Event").withParam("Tap"). In my code it's will looks more complex not a simple outputting. I just use printer to describe my question in more simple way.

Comment: Edited the answer above to address this! Let me know if that's sufficient.